# Hashing don't care bits

Tags: data-structures, hash, classification

I have a set of rules for Deep Packet Inspection (DPI), means, when a packet arrives, I should go over the set of rules to find a matching rule in order to decide what action to take (Accept/Deny).

Our algorithm is hashing that set of rules twice so that we get a small chunks of sub-rules set. So when a packet comes, we "send" it to the same hash-tables so that we end up searching if there is a matching rule only in a small chunk of rules.
The only problem is the rules with don't care bits, we thought about duplicating each rule with don't care bits, but this will take a vast memory, since we are hashing a 17bits out of the 104 in the first place and 16bits out of the 104 bits in the second place, thus if the whole 17 and 16 bits for a specific rule are don't care, there should be an extra 2^33 entries for each rule(!). We are okay with lot of pre-processing time.

[image]